# Style a Sencha touch list of items

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm looking for a sample of how to style a list on the results returned from Sencha.

Do I need 100's of line of custom CSS, or are there some predefined styles I need to apply to make my app look native device like?

Answer (score 3):

The default styling should look OK: at least, consistent with the rest of the Touch UI.

Simply provide an itemTpl: property and bind the list to a store: you should see the items appearing in a list like:

[image]

You can of course elaborate on the itemTpl as much as you like. There are also some 'standard' UI behaviors such as the disclosure buttons and index bars. See this screencast for examples: http://vimeo.com/19245335

And finally, of course, it's all just HTML & CSS, so you can go completely crazy with the styling if you want. Check: http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/12/17/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch/

Answer (score 1):

Use this to make it vertically center aligned always:

```
.x-list .x-list-item{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the default download of Sencha Touch there is a folder called Kitchen Sink in the demos. There's a basic css file in this demo that you can use as a starting point.

Also, you could give the list or nestedlist a class with the cls:'yourClass' and then, in the source of your project, check the nested divs and their classes...

Another option is to use style:'background-color:black;color:white;' inside the component to get basic styling.

Your best bet would be to check out the kitchen sink special css file as it's indented in a right way and very clear to beginners.